# Convert SQL statement into mySQL stored procedure

Tags: java, mysql, spring, stored-procedures

I have a piece of SQL that works out the rank of a golfer on the leaderboard.  I'm pretty new to Spring and I don't think I can execute this using Spring JDBC so I think I need to convert it to a mySQL stored procedure.

Can anyone give me some pointers as to what I need to convert?  Simply putting CREATE PROCEDURE and the param list around this doesn't work.

```
SET @rank = 1, @prev_val = NULL, @prev_rank = NULL;
SELECT rank FROM
(
 SELECT @rank := IF(@prev_val!=winnings,@prev_rank+1,@rank) AS rank
     , @prev_val := winnings AS winnings
     , @prev_rank := @rank AS prevRank
     , t.golferID
  FROM 
     (
        select g.golferID, sum(winnings) as winnings 
        from results r
        join resultDetails rd on r.resultID = rd.resultID
        join golfers g on rd.golferID = g.golferID
        where r.status = 'C' and r.compID = 1 
        group by golferID order by winnings desc
     ) AS t
) AS showRank WHERE golferID = 16
```

Comment: You should accept an answer, Paul. The idea is to mark correct and most helpful answers here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will get you started:

```
drop procedure if exists get_golfer_rank;

delimiter #

create procedure get_golfer_rank
(
p_golferID int unsigned
)
proc_main:begin

set @rank = 0;

select 
...
where golferID = p_golferID;

end proc_main #

delimiter ;


call get_golfer_rank(18);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your work out is fine - f00 had assumed you would want to only call out each golfers rank thru a given param - hence the construct...

```
create procedure get_golfer_rank
(
p_golferID int unsigned
)
```

and...

```
where golferID = p_golferID;
```

restricts to a single golfer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the leads.  I worked it out.  Roughly speaking it's

```
drop procedure if exists getRank;

delimiter $$

create procedure getRank()
begin

    set @rank = 1; 
    set @prev_val = NULL;
    set @prev_rank = NULL;

    select rank from
    (
     select @rank := if(@prev_val!=winnings,@prev_rank+1,@rank) as rank
         , @prev_val := winnings as winnings
         , @prev_rank := @rank as prevrank
         , t.golferid
      from 
         (
            select g.golferid, sum(winnings) as winnings 
            from results r
            join resultdetails rd on r.resultid = rd.resultid
            join golfers g on rd.golferid = g.golferid
            where r.status = 'c' and r.compid = 1 
            group by golferid order by winnings desc
         ) as t
    ) as showrank where golferid = 16;

end; $$

delimiter ;
```

Comment: dont you want to pass in a golfer id as a param ??